# How to plot this histograms as a line graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, plot

Let's say I have this histogram plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={a small bar,a medium bar,a large bar},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (a small bar,42)
        (a medium bar,50)
        (a large bar,80)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I convert this to a line plot style?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? I just removed `[ybar,fill=blue]` from `\addplot` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={a small bar,a medium bar,a large bar},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (a small bar,42)
        (a medium bar,50)
        (a large bar,80)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can add any number of lines (with legends) as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend style={
            at={(0.5,0.8),anchor=north}
        },
    symbolic x coords={precission, recall, f1-score},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
        (precission,42)         (recall,50)         (f1-score,80)         };
    \addlegendentry{Some}
    \addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},blue,thick,dashed] coordinates {
        (precission,48)        (recall,58)        (f1-score,89)        };
    \addlegendentry{other}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or simply add a node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={precission, recall, f1-score},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
        (precission,42)         (recall,50)         (f1-score,80)
                 }node[pos=0.7,below,anchor=west]{some};
    \addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},blue,thick,dashed] coordinates {
        (precission,48)        (recall,58)        (f1-score,89)
                }node[pos=0.7,above,anchor=east]{other};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But be careful not to make your x tick labels crowded as you are using symbolic x coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the help, what about adding more lines with different colors, let's say: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={precission, recall, f1-score},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (precission,42)
        (recall,50)
        (f1-score,80)
        };
 \addplot coordinates_2{
    (precission,42)
       (recall,50)
       (f1-score,80)
       };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`

Comment: Any idea of how to aporach this?, thanks!

Comment: @ml_guy I have updated. Does it help?

Comment: How could I put the meaning of each line?. Thanks!!

Comment: @ml_guy You can put a legend or add a node.

Comment: @ml_guy Please see the update. For more details, `textdoc pgfplots` from terminal or visit `www.texdoc.net` and type `pgfplots` in the search window to get the manual.